# Can I force Django’s per-site cache to use only each page’s path as its key?

Tags: django, caching, memcached, django-cache

I’ve developed a Django site. There’s pretty much a 1-to-1 relationship between model instances in the dabatase, and pages on the site.

I’d like to cache each page on the site (using memcached as the cache back-end). The site isn’t too big — according to a back-of-an-envelope calculation, the whole thing should fit into a fairly small amount of RAM — and the data doesn’t change particularly frequently, so the entire site could effectively live in the cache.

However, when the data does change, I want the cache to reflect that immediately, so ideally I’d like each model instance to be able to clear its own page from the cache when saved.

The way I imagined I’d do that is to cache pages with their URL as the key. Then each model instance can use its URL (which it knows via `get_absolue_url()`) to clear its page from the cache.

Can I make Django’s per site caching mechanism use page URLs as the cache key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any option to control the cache key, and the implementation in Django doesn't suggest there is any. The code to generate the cache key for a request through the cache middleware lives in `django.utils.cache.get_cache_key` (to know where to fetch from the cache) and `learn_cache_key` (to know where to set the cache). You could monkey-patch these functions not to take headers into account like this:

```
from django.utils import cache
from django.conf import settings

def get_path_cache_key(request, key_prefix=None):
    if key_prefix is None:
        key_prefix = settings.CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX
    return cache._generate_cache_key(request, [], key_prefix)
    # passing an empty headerlist so only request.path is taken into account

cache.get_cache_key = get_path_cache_key
cache.learn_cache_key = get_path_cache_key
```

This will internally take an MD5 hash of the path, add a potential prefix, and also take the current locale (language) into account. You could further change it to omit the prefix and the language. I would not recommend using the plain path without hashing it, as memcached does not allow keys longer than 250 characters or containing whitespaces, according to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#cache-key-warnings). This should not be a problem because you can just apply `get_path_cache_key` to the URL from `get_absolute_url()` as well and clear that page.